# Diablo 3 for Console Specifically for Ps3 and Xbox 360 Version Acquisition

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I'm aware that the next gen consoles, PS4 and Xbox 1, are operating on patch 2.3, which brings much of the same content that PC users are experiencing at this time. However as I understand it the PS3 and Xbox 360 versions did not, and will not, receive patches beyond their day 1 status.

I only just recently purchased Diablo 3: Ultimate Evil Edition for my Playstation 3 and I'm having a very hard time establishing where exactly in the patch timeline the game is frozen at.  Information gleamed from google and various forum searches point towards the original Console games as having Nightmare and Hell difficulties in the old D3 style, however my game clearly is updated at least to the point of having Torment Difficulties. I'm completly lost as to what content my console game has and does not have. Is there any way to figure this all out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blizzard announced before the release of "Reaper of Souls" that they would not support further updates for ps3 or xbox360. So if you got the expansion, you are playing patch 2.0 with some hot fixes they added due bugs with enchantments.

I have been searching for links to support the explanation but can't find any so i'm talking from my memory.

Comment: 8 days before release they confirmed the non-support and the version is either [2.0.5 or 2.0.6](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/15701235148#19)